# update checkbox isChecked stauts in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Parent component

```
class Parent extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        checkedView:[
                {id: 1, value: "A", isChecked: false},
                {id: 2, value: "B", isChecked: true},
                {id: 3, value: "C", isChecked: true},
                {id: 4, value: "D", isChecked: true}
            ],
        }
    }
   handleCheck=(e)=>{
       this.setState({ isChecked: e.target.checked});
   }
   render(){
     return(
        <div>
             <Selection checkedView={this.state.checkedView} handleCheck={this.handleCheck} />
             <Content checkedView={this.state.checkedView} />
        </div>
     );
   }
}
```

Selection component

```
class Selection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      checkedView: this.props.checkedView
    }
  }

  handleCheck = (event) => {
    let checkedView = this.props.checkedView;
      checkedView.forEach( item => {
        if(item.value === event.target.value){
          item.isChecked = event.target.checked
        }
      })
    this.setState({
      checkedView: checkedView
    })
    this.props.handleCheck(event)
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <ul className="morefeatures">{
          this.props.checkedView.map((selection, index) => {
            return (<CheckBox  key={index} handleCheck={this.handleCheck} {...selection}  />)
          })
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CHECKBOX

```
export const CheckBox = props => {
    return (
      <li>
       <input key={props.id} onClick={props.handleCheck} type="checkbox" checked={props.isChecked} value={props.value} /> {props.value}
      </li>
    )
}
```

I have a parent component that controls the content, and the selection component should be able to update its change to the parent component so other child components then can access the value of the checkbox.
When a (or multiple) checkboxes are checked, Content Component receives signal to display relevant content, something like that

The isChecked not change its status no mater the checkbox is checked or not checked.

So how should I modify the code to make the isChecked really work?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the right state. `this.setState({ isChecked: e.target.checked});` adds a new variable `isChecked` to the state. What you want is find the right entry within `checkedView` and update that object. I would pass down the `id` to the checkbox and on `onClick`, I would call `handleChecked` which receives not only the event but also the `id` of the checkbox. In `handleChecked` you can then find the right checkbox based on the `id` and update that one accordingly.

In parent:

```
   handleCheck=(id, checked)=>{
       // deep copy old state (check out lodash for a nicer deepCopy)
       const checkedView = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.checkedView));
       const checkBox = checkedView.find(view => view.id === id);
       checkBox.isChecked = checked;
       // update whole object of new state
       this.setState(checkedView);
   }
```

In Selection:

!**Warning**! You were altering props, never update props, that's the job of the parent. You also don't need to put the checkedView in the state in Selection, you receive it as a prob, just pass it down.

```
handleCheck = (event, id) => {
    this.props.handleCheck(id, e.target.checked)
}
```

```
class Selection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  handleCheck = (event, id) => {
    this.props.handleCheck(id, e.target.checked)
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <ul className="morefeatures">{
          this.props.checkedView.map((selection) => {
            return (<CheckBox key={selection.id} handleCheck={this.handleCheck} {...selection}  />)
          })
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In Checkbox, wrap the handleCheck to pass it both the event and the id to identify the checkbox.

```
<input onClick={(e) => props.handleCheck(e, props.id)} type="checkbox" checked={props.isChecked} value={props.value} /> {props.value}
```

Comment: Thx for the solution, but I still need help. I replaced by your code, but then the checkboxes are unable to check/uncheck. So I changed the setState to this.setState({checkedView: checkedView}); but its status is still not changed, checked remains checked from Inspect

Comment: Of course! Do you see any errors in the console? Feel free to try the version from SakoBu as well. I tried to keep your overall code structure as is but the version SakoBu proposed is very clean. You may want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question I think this is what you're looking for - your architecture and logic are a bit off and you've coded yourself into a corner...- Two components (Parent and Child)

Here is your Parent: (keeps the state and all methods that manipulate it)

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        checkedView: [
            { id: 1, value: 'A', isChecked: false },
            { id: 2, value: 'B', isChecked: true },
            { id: 3, value: 'C', isChecked: true },
            { id: 4, value: 'D', isChecked: true }
        ]
    };

    handleCheck = (id) => {
        this.setState({
            checkedView: this.state.checkedView.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === id) {
                    return {
                        ...item,
                        isChecked: !item.isChecked
                    };
                } else {
                    return item;
                }
            })
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.checkedView.map((item) => (
                    <Child key={item.id} item={item} handleCheck={this.handleCheck} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is your Child:

import React from 'react';

```
export default function Child({ item, handleCheck }) {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => handleCheck(item.id)}>
            {item.value}
            <input type='checkbox' defaultChecked={item.isChecked} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is a live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ddqwpb?file=src%2FApp.js

I'm guessing you can understand what the code is doing... if not ask...